# How to split a string by in angularjs?

Tags: javascript

Ihave a problem when I use js.I have a string=>`"c:0.1|d:0.2"` and I need output like this=> `c:10%，d:20%`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```js
var str = "c:0.1|d:0.2";

console.log(
  str
  // split string by delimiter `|`
  .split('|')
  // iterate and generate result string
  .map(function(v) {
    // split string based on `:`
    var s = v.split(':')
      // generate the string
    return s[0] + ':' + (Number(s[1]) * 100) + "%"
  })
  // join them back to the format
  .join()
)
```

---

You can also use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with [capturing group regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a callback function.

```js
var str = "c:0.1|d:0.2";

console.log(
  str.replace(/\b([a-z]:)(0\.\d{1,2})(\|?)/gi, function(m, m1, m2, m3) {
    return m1 +
      (Number(m2) * 100) + // calculate the percentage value
      (m3 ? "%," : "%") // based on the captured value put `,`
  })
)
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/trve5t/2)

Answer (score 1):

It's not angular issue, you can use simple logic, use substring take value after the : and multiply by 100 to get the value as 10 or respective.